# FFmpeg .m2v copy looses quality

Tags: command-line, video, ffmpeg

I am copying parts of a .m2v file, but somehow the quality of the new video file gets really bad.

Any idea what I am doing wrong or how to improve the command.

My current command looks like this:

> ffmpeg -v quiet -y -i full.m2v -acodec copy -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:10
>   -sn part.m2v

Comment: Use `-c copy`...

Comment: BTW: When copying from a compressed video stream, you need to make sure the resulting stream starts with an I-frame (full frame). Otherwise, you’ll get a corrupted picture until the first I-frame.

Answer (score 0):

`-acodec` only refers to audio streams. (It is the same as `-codec:a` or `-c:a`.)

You should use `-c copy` to copy all streams, that is, video, audio and subtitles.

If only the video stream should be copied, use `-c:v copy`. In this case, ffmpeg will automatically choose an audio encoder, depending on the output format, and re-encode the first audio stream it finds. This is not preferable unless you also control the audio bitrate or quality.

<sub>PS: `-ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:10` can be abbreviated to `-t 10`, in that particular case.</sub>

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer I must only copy the video stream (.m2v)

Comment: Then, as with the audio case, use `-c:v copy`. But it's not recommended. If you want to disable audio, use `-an`.

Comment: where do I need to place the `-an`, what would the whole command look like?